# Яке походження слова "баский" (кінь)?

Tags: етимологія

СУМ-11 дає таке означення слова "баский":

> [БАСКИ́Й](http://sum.in.ua/s/baskyj), а, е. Дуже швидкий, прудкий, жвавий (перев. про коней).

Ще є "баско" - "[кінь] баско вигравав".

Яке походження цього слова? [Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) української мови не пояснює цього слова, там є лише "баска - кофта з оборками" і "баскак - татарський урядовець".

Comment: Може від слова "баскак"? Мовляв, не встиг врожай зібрати, як баскаки (збирачі податків) налетіли та все повідбирали...

Comment: Ви пропустили, там у тому ж Етим.словнику ще є *«баскали́читися»* — чинити опір, пручатися, а також *«баскали́ти»* — рватися, квапитися. Припускаю, що це і є відповіддю, але треба б поґуґлити ще пруфів.

Comment: Цікава реакція на це слово гугл-перекладача: на рос.- резвый, на білорус. - жвавы, а на інші - щось пов'язане з "басками" (гадаю, іспанськими). Коли вказуєш, автоматичне визначення мови - визначає "монгольська".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Як правильно вказав bytebuster, корисною є інша стаття, щодо слова "баскаличитися". Але "баский" походить не від "баскаличитися", а від спільного "пращура" - слова "баса", тобто краса.

Ось стаття щодо баскаличитися:
[image: баскаличитися]

Словник Даля щодо слова [баский](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/205918) відсилає до слова [баса](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/205890) (краса, ошатність, вродливість) де серед прикладів є "басенька дівчина, їй би ще й хлопця баского".